# NotificationListenerService in Android Marshmallow

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, logout, firebase-notifications

I need to clear my applications notifications when the user logout's from the app. I am not generating notifications using NotificationBuilder my notifications are directly generated from the server for the app. I am able to to clear my notifications on user logout in android lolipop and below.
But for marshmallow when user gives notification access permission from settings I don't receive any notifications for marshmallow. Need some help regarding this.
I am receiving notifications from Firebase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is:

```
((NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).cancelAll();
```

No need for notification access and all the other logics.